# How to establish a viewModel to a ContentControl

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, contentcontrol

I've got a usercontrol which defines a ContentControl like this:

```
<ContentControl x:Name="PART_contentHost" Grid.Row="1"/>
```

In the viewmodel I will get a viewModel which will be displayed inside the contentControl. To establish the link with the view I have a datatemplate that establish the relationship between both of them.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:Test1ViewModel}">
        <Views:Test1View />
</DataTemplate>
```

This means that I want Test1ViewModel to be shown inside the contentControl. I am not able to stablish that in my code C#.

```
//this gets the contentControl from de template
contentHost = this.Template.FindName(contentHostName, this) as ContentControl; 
//this assigns the test1ViewModel
contentHost.Content = content
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Say more about the problem or what isn't working.  Are you getting an exception?

Comment: what is the type of your viewmodel/view being loaded into the content control.  Is it a usercontrol, page, etc?  Show the code where you define and get "content"

Comment: Your `<DataTemplate>` does not set the content, it sets the `DataContext`. All it does is tell WPF that when it tries to render a `Test1ViewModel` to the VisualTree, it should draw it using a `Test1View` and set the `DataContext` (data layer) behind the `Test1View` to be the ViewModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not shared enough code for me to be sure what you are trying to do. While there are cases in which you will need to parse templates, most often there is a better way. So here is how I understand your case in a MVVM context, can you do it this way?

[image]

Xaml:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Test1ViewModel}">
        <local:Test1View />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding ContentModel}" />
</Grid>
```

Test1View:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.Test1View" 
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Background="Beige" Padding="5"  />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Address}" Background="PeachPuff" Padding="5" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

ViewModels:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private Test1ViewModel _contentModel;
    public Test1ViewModel ContentModel { get { return _contentModel; } set { _contentModel = value; OnPropertyChanged("ContentModel"); } }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        this.ContentModel = new Test1ViewModel() { Name = "John Higgins", Address = "Wishaw" };
    }

}

public class Test1ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name { get { return _name; } set { _name = value; OnPropertyChanged("Name"); } }

    private string _address;
    public string Address { get { return _address; } set { _address = value; OnPropertyChanged("Address"); } }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution!! Indeed I use MVVM and both answers are allright, I missed one little thing about stablishing the viewmodel to the contentControl's content.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something of that nature before. 
This code should get you started.

```
    public void FindAndSetTemplateContent( ContentControl target, ViewModelBase item)
    {
        if (target == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("target");

        if (item == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("item");

        var template = target.TryFindResource(new DataTemplateKey(item.GetType())) as DataTemplate; // this will pick up your resource for the viewmodel
        if (template == null)
            return null;

        var content = template.LoadContent() as ContentControl ;
        if (content != null)
        {
            content.DataContext = item;
        }
        return content;
    }
```

Comment: This is allright also for getting the template item, very useful. Thank you!