# Why is Datatemplate not working properly?

Tags: c#, wpf

I use the code below to display the data, but the result seems to show the ToString() method of the object.

It seems to be failing to recognize that Model is of type model.

I looked at the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15484824/15181473). My code should work.

Why is the data not showing? What did i do wrong?

Xaml:

```
  <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DT" DataType="{x:Type local:model}">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">Id</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Id}"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">Name</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <ContentControl Width="400" Content="{Binding Path=Model}"  />
    </StackPanel>
```

Codebehind:

```
public class model : ViewModelBase
  {
    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
      get { return name; }
      set
      {
        name = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged("Name");
      }
    }
    private int id;
    public int Id
    {
      get { return id; }
      set
      {
        id = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged("Id");
      }
    }
  
  }

  public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
      var handler = PropertyChanged;
      if (handler != null)
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
  }
  public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
  { 
    private model model;
    public model Model
    {
      get { return model; }
      set
      {
        model=value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged("Model");
      }
    }
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
      Model = new model() { Id = 5, Name = "John" };
    }
  }
```

The result is as follows：

[image]

Comment: You're incorrectly implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`: your code will fire the `PropertyChanged` event every time a setter is invoked, even if the value itself doesn't change.

Comment: Hi,@Dai. I cancel the inheritance of ViewModelBase and copy the OnPropertyChanged in the link to the model and MainWindowViewModel. Nothing has changed. How can I achieve the effect in the link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must not set the `x:Key` attribute on the `<DataTemplate>`, because that breaks the mechanism that automatically applies the DataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:model}">
```

See the [DataType Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.datatemplate.datatype?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#remarks):

> ... When you set this property to the data type without specifying an x:Key, the DataTemplate gets applied automatically to data objects of that type. Note that when you do that the x:Key is set implicitly.